# Problems with spyService and throwError() in Angular / Jasmine unit test;

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I am having trouble mocking a service that returns an error in a Component's unit test file. My app is written in Angular 6 with TypeScript and my unit tests are written in Jasmine.

In my component I call a method in the `ngOnInit` and within this method I call a method on a imported service, should this fail a boolean property of my component called `isLoading` should be set to false. Here is some minimised code of my component to give an understanding of the code I am wishing to test.

```js
export class CylindersListComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

public isLoading: boolean = true;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
      // do stuff ... I have removed some code here
      this.loadCylinderList();
  }

  public loadCylinderList() {
    this.cylindersService.getCylinderList().subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.cylinders = res;
      // do stuff ... I have removed lots of code here
      this.isLoading = false;
    }, (error: any) => {
      this.isLoading = false;
      throw new Error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

I wish to mock the `loadCylinderList` method being called and the cylindersService.getCylinderList returning an error. Thus once this is done I wish to assert (or make sure) that the `isLoading` property is false. Now I have my unit test set up like so, however this doesn't seem to work (or more likely I have implemented the test incorrectly). Once again I have minimised the code or put `...` where data is returned.

```js
describe('CylindersListComponent', () => {
let fixture: ComponentFixture<CylindersListComponent>;
let instance: CylindersListComponent;

const spyCylinderService = jasmine.createSpyObj<CylindersService>(
'CylindersService', ['getCylinderList', 'getListPaged']);

spyCylinderService.getListPaged.and.returnValue(observedData); // observedData is set earler in the file 


beforeEach(async(() => {
    // inject the spies. We use override component because the service is injected
    // in component not in the module. (deeper level)
    TestBed.overrideComponent(CylindersListComponent, {
      set: {
        providers: [
          {provide: CylindersService, useValue: spyCylinderService}
        ],
        template: '<input #filter>'
      }
    })
    // prepare CylinderComponent for the tests
    // Allows overriding default providers, directives, pipes
      .configureTestingModule({
        imports: [...],
        declarations: [
          CylindersListComponent
        ],
        schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
      })
      .compileComponents().then(() => {
      // arrange
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(CylindersListComponent);
      instance = fixture.componentInstance;
      spyCylinderService.getCylinderList.and.returnValue({...});
    });
}));

it('should be false after error while loading data', () => {
    // arrange
    spyCylinderService.getCylinderList.and.throwError('error');
    instance.isLoading = true;
    spyOn(instance, 'loadCylinderList' as any).and.callThrough();

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(instance.isLoading).toBe(false);
});
```

This sounds like a very open question and I apologise but what I am doing wrong with my test / spyOn method. I am sure I am getting a failed test / error as my implementation to raise / mock the error is incorrect: `spyCylinderService.getCylinderList.and.throwError('error');`

If anyone can see what I am doing wrong I would be most appreciative. The error from the test console is as follows if that is of any help:

```
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.12.6) CylindersListComponent isLoading should be false after error while loading data FAILED
    Error: error
    error properties: Object({ ngDebugContext: DebugContext_({ view: Object({ def: Object({ factory: Function, nodeFlags: 33800449, rootNodeFlags: 33554433, nodeMatchedQueries: 0, flags: 0, nodes: [ Object({ nodeIndex: 0, parent: null, renderParent: null, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 0, flags: 33554433, childFlags: 246016, directChildFlags: 246016, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object({  }), matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object({  }), ngContentIndex: null, childCount: 4, bindings: [  ], bindingFlags: 0, outputs: [  ], element: Object({ ns: '', name: 'cylinders', attrs: [  ], template: null, componentProvider: Object({ nodeIndex: 4, parent: <circular reference: Object>, renderParent: <circular reference: Object>, bindingIndex: 0, outputIndex: 0, checkIndex: 4, flags: 245760, childFlags: 0, directChildFlags: 0, childMatchedQueries: 0, matchedQueries: Object, matchedQueryIds: 0, references: Object, ngContentIndex: -1, childCount: 0, bindings: Array, bindingFlags: 0, outputs: Array,  ...
        at <Jasmine>
```

Update: I am sure how I am raising the error is wrong as if I should put a `console.log` in the component where the error is caught nothing is written to the console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason can be that isLoading is updated asynchronously. So you should wait till all change detections and updates end.

```js
it('should be false after error while loading data', async(() => {
    // arrange
    spyCylinderService.getCylinderList.and.returnValue(Observable.throw('error'));
    instance.isLoading = true;
    spyOn(instance, 'loadCylinderList' as any).and.callThrough();

    // act
    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable()
      .then(() =>{
            expect(instance.isLoading).toBe(false);
       });    
}));
```

Comment: Thanks however it still gives me the same error... I am sure the way I am throwing the error is wrong? If I should put a console.log in the component where the error is caught nothing is written to the console.

Comment: @MikeSav sorry I didn't notice it as first, I edited my answer, so it returns observable that throws an error instead of throwing the error in service call itself.

Comment: Thanks for the update however I am sad to say that that doesn't work either, the console now ouptuts `{
    "message": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: error thrown",
    "str": "An error was thrown in afterAll\nUncaught Error: error thrown"
  }`

Comment: Sorry, I missed to wrap the async around the test. When doing this i have notice that instance.isLoading is false however the test still fails with the message above and the following `Failed: error
 error properties: Object({ longStack: 'Error: error...`

Comment: Also I noticed that when I remove the fixture.detectChanges(); the test does not fail because of the error...but obviously the test fails as nothing is updated!

Comment: I fixed this! I just removed the `throw new Error(error);`from the component

Comment: @MikeSav do you mean that your original code worked after your removal?

Comment: For those using RXJS 6+ it's now `and.returnValue(throwError('error'));`